# Print value from json blob in oracle database

Tags: json, oracle

Within a table (prov) in my database, I have a column (data_json) of type BLOB that contains data of type JSON.
The JSON structure has two types (can be more but now only two).

For the current two types, I am trying to print a specific value which is the type within the entity.

Example of the first json (type1):

```
{
    "agent": {
        "iss:02228ba5-554d-4db7-802b-89ff360f2315": {
            "iss:idcode": "000005",
            "idd:type": "idd:org"
        }
    },
    "entity": {
        "iss:754df246-e3f7-46f6-b53c-f6f2770177f6": {
            "iss:algoritme1": "d5ad30e753204063bf15aea24805d2c3",
            "idd:type": "type1",
            "iss:algoritme2": "20ea978f31a14c7bac1415a9d3a50195",
            "iss:identifier": "test1"
        }
    }
}
```

Example of the secound json (type2):

```
{
    "entity" : {
        "iss:132b7a2c-e598-419a-a3a8-6adb4aa86d6b" : {
            "idd:type" : [ "type2" ],
            "iss:identifier" : [ "test2" ]
        },
        "iss:fc36e29c-8ce9-4f3e-a8f9-fa4b32d5d2f0" : {
            "idd:value" : [ "23aeb0dd598f49c9b8fd065196724220" ],
            "iss:algoritme" : [ "algoritme1" ],
            "idd:type" : [ "tdd" ]
        },
        "iss:b53ae8ca-df09-4a66-9727-6f8a9bf1afcb" : {
            "idd:value" : [ "65d3d05ce8bc4a35b2a5dd96e377a3d8" ],
            "iss:algoritme" : [ "algoritme2" ],
            "idd:type" : [ "tdd" ]
        }
    },
    "agent" : {
        "iss:818c5dff-f08d-4831-b750-4887a10f1a50" : {
            "idd:type" : [ { "type" : "idd:NAME", "$" : "idd:org" } ],
            "iss:idcode" : [ "000005" ]
        }
    }
}
```

With the following query

```
SELECT id,
       JSON_VALUE(data_json, '$.entity.*."idd:type"[0]') type,
       data_json
FROM prov p;
```

I am getting the right output for the type1 but it's null for the type2 (It supposed to be type2)

| ID | TYPE | DATA_JSON |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4472 | type1 | (BLOB) |
| 4792 | (null) | (BLOB) |

Any idea about what is the problem here?

update----------------------------------------------

The second json (type2) can come in different order or with more elements within the entity:
but the **"idd:type" : [ "type2" ]** will be present only one time but also it can be type3 at some point.

```
{
    "entity" : {
        "iss:fc36e29c-8ce9-4f3e-a8f9-fa4b32d5d2f0" : {
            "idd:value" : [ "23aeb0dd598f49c9b8fd065196724220" ],
            "iss:algoritme" : [ "algoritme1" ],
            "idd:type" : [ "tdd" ]
        },
        "iss:all9829c-8ce9-4fe3-a9a9-fa4b35a7d2f0" : {
            "idd:value" : [ "23aeb0dd598f49c9b8fd065196724220" ],
            "iss:algoritme" : [ "algoritme2" ],
            "idd:type" : [ "tdd" ]
        },
        "iss:132b7a2c-e598-419a-a3a8-6adb4aa86d6b" : {
            "idd:type" : [ "type2" ],
            "iss:identifier" : [ "test2" ]
        },
        "iss:b53ae8ca-df09-4a66-9727-6f8a9bf1afcb" : {
            "idd:value" : [ "65d3d05ce8bc4a35b2a5dd96e377a3d8" ],
            "iss:algoritme" : [ "algoritme3" ],
            "idd:type" : [ "tdd" ]
        }
    },
    "agent" : {
        "iss:818c5dff-f08d-4831-b750-4887a10f1a50" : {
            "idd:type" : [ { "type" : "idd:NAME", "$" : "idd:org" } ],
            "iss:idcode" : [ "000005" ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any attribute/path values that will provide an information of what type value shoud be extracted? For example if there were `"idd:type" : [ "type3" ]` in `$.entity."iss:fc36e29c-8ce9-4f3e-a8f9-fa4b32d5d2f0"` how should we know that the result should not be retrieved from it?

Comment: There is still not accurate data regarding other types, but assuming it will be at the same path and have similar keys as type2 schema, so the different will be the type name.

Comment: Then it is unclear if you need to get `'type2'` or `'tdd'` as in example above. If you want to restrict the type by some list of possible values (for example, `type1` and `type2` only as per your current description), then it is quite different question: how do you distinguish `type1` and `type2`? By the number of keys in the `entity` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your second JSON you have multiple `iss:*` values, and thus multiple `idd:type` values within them. Your query returns `NULL ON ERROR` by default, so the result you see is null:

```
SELECT id,
       JSON_VALUE(data_json, '$.entity.*."idd:type"[0]') type
FROM prov p;
```

| ID | TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| 4472 | type1 |
| 4792 | *null* |

But if you add the `ERROR ON ERROR` then you see:

```
SELECT id,
       JSON_VALUE(data_json, '$.entity.*."idd:type"[0]' ERROR ON ERROR) type
FROM prov p;
```

```
ORA-40470: JSON_VALUE evaluated to multiple values
```

As the `iss:*` elements are independent and not part of an array I don't think you can really target one of them. You can't, for example, do `'$.entity.*."idd:type"[0]'` - that gets the same error.

You could instead use `JSON_TABLE` to get all of the type values:

```
SELECT p.id,
       j.type
FROM prov p
CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE (
  p.data_json,
  '$.entity.*."idd:type"'
  COLUMNS (
    type PATH '$[*]'
  )
) j
```

| ID | TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| 4472 | type1 |
| 4792 | type2 |
| 4792 | tdd |
| 4792 | tdd |

... and if you only want the 'first' one you can add and filter on an `ORDINALITY` value:

```
SELECT p.id,
       j.type
FROM prov p
CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE (
  p.data_json,
  '$.entity.*."idd:type"'
  COLUMNS (
    rn FOR ORDINALITY,
    type PATH '$[*]'
  )
) j
WHERE j.rn = 1
```

| ID | TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| 4472 | type1 |
| 4792 | type2 |

Which assumes the type value you care about is always going to be the first one in the parent entity element, of course.

Or, pick the one that has an `iss:identifier` as well, if that is a valid thing to check for (I'm just guessing from the sample data):

```
SELECT p.id,
       j.type
FROM prov p
CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE (
  p.data_json,
  '$.entity.*'
  COLUMNS (
    type PATH '$."idd:type"[*]',
    identifier PATH '$."iss:identifier"[*]'
  )
) j
WHERE j.identifier is not null
```

| ID | TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| 4472 | type1 |
| 4792 | type2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oSOApc4o)

Answer (score 3):

This is because

> The SQL/JSON function [JSON_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/JSON_VALUE.html#GUID-C7F19D36-1E75-4CB2-AE67-ADFBAD23CBC2) finds a specified **scalar JSON value** in JSON data and returns it as a SQL value.

But `$.entity.*."idd:type"[0]` points to an array of strings. You need to use `json_query` for this:

```
select
  id,
  json_query(
    data_json,
    '$.entity.*."idd:type"[0]'
    with conditional array wrapper
  )as type_
from prov p;
```

| ID | TYPE_ |
| --- | --- |
| 4472 | "type1" |
| 4792 | ["type2","tdd","tdd"] |

You may extract the first element of this array using another `json_value` function:

```
select
  id,
  json_value(json_query(
    data_json,
    '$.entity.*."idd:type"[0]'
    with conditional array wrapper
  ), '$[0]') as type_
from prov p;
```

| ID | TYPE_ |
| --- | --- |
| 4472 | type1 |
| 4792 | type2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LA8qrjgZ)

Comment: The order can be different as the type can be the second or the third. thanks for the explanation

Comment: It would be better to clarify all the requirements in the question to provide all criteria to account.

Comment: That's right, i wasn't aware about the deferent in data till i have tested the qury!
How the conditions will be when the type can be in a different order?

Comment: @Ali Please add this additional info to the question along with the rule to select the "correct" value. Then I'll try to update the answer accordingly or someone will add an answer which covers such case.